# Access IIS hosted web app that uses AzureAD credentials via PowerShell for use of APIs

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an IIS hosted blazor server .net core web app that uses AzureAd to login and my app has some functionality I want to expose to APIs and I am trying to run a PowerShell script that access' my web app to run the methods.

However, I am running into login issues and cannot seem to login to my app.

this is my web apps appsettings.json and currently works and logs in when accessing https://localhost:8080/ which connects to my Azure app registration for my app.

```
 "AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "mycompanyname.onmicrosoft.com",
"TenantId": "redacted",
"ClientId": "redacted",
"ClientSecret": "redacted",
"ClientCertificates": [
], 
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
 },
```

When attempting to connect via PowerShell,
I am able to receive an access_token when using the method below:

```
$tenantid = "<tenantid>"    
$clientId = "<clientid>"    
$ClientSecret = "<clientsecret>"

$Resource = "<resourceid>"

$RequestAccessTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantid/oauth2/token"

$body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$clientId&client_secret=$ClientSecret&resource=$Resource"

$Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

My problem is, I cant seem to find out how to use this access_token, to pass to my website to login, unless I am not fully understanding how Microsoft authenticates and authorizes.

I have been working on this problem for a few days and in need of help.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To pass your token, you need to build an authorization header and pass it down to subsequent calls afterward.

```
# Build header from access token
$Headers = @{Headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $($token.Access_token)" } }

# Splat Headers onto any calls that require you to be authenticated.
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'Https://YourApp.com/Something' -Method Get @Headers
```

Additional note:

If not already present, you will need to authorize Powershell Client ID to use the app registration.

This can be done in your App registration.

- Go to Expose An API
- Add a User_Impersonation scope
- Add the following client application: 1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2

[image: App registration]

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work and I may have to review my Azure App Registration configurations to make sure I am able to access from the desktop, as opposed to from the web browser.

Comment: @Brnsn See my edit. If not configured, you need to go into Expose An API and add the Azure Powershell GUID as an authorized client ID so you can actually connect from the desktop.

Comment: I did not have that, but I will try that, thank you!